# Using a USB keyboard to mimic a joystick in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-xp, keyboard

Is it possible to mimic an external keyboard as a joystick so that I can use the second keyboard as joystick in Windows XP?

Answer (score 1):

TeamPlayer might help you on this one. 
It allows more than one set of keyboard/mouse per computer
then you'd have to set up some keys on each keyboard in your game's options.

http://www.dicolab.com/wunderworks/ (I think it's free for personal use)